# How to decrypt a private key in Java (without BC openssl)

Tags: java, encryption, bouncycastle, jce, pkcs#8

Is it possible decrypt an encrypted RSA (or others, shouldn't matter) private keys using JCE and/or BouncyCastle provider (not using openssl bundle)?

I can read unencrypted keys just fine using PrivateKeyFactory.

Googling this gets me through examples of using PEMReader (from BC openssl bundle) that has a password applied to it, but - don't want to use openssl bundle, don't necessarily want to use PEM format, and I can decode PEM using PemReader (from provider bundle). It's what can I do with it afterwards is the question.

I'm looking for some mega-function, or a series thereof that can do it, i.e. I am not looking into parsing the ASN1 of the encrypted key, figuring out the encryption method, passing the input through the cipher, etc.

Comment: You can decrypt anything in Java that was encrypted using a cipher that's supported by Java.

Comment: Do you have the keys in the key store secured with password?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have an encrypted PKCS#8 key in binary format (i.e. not in PEM format) the following code shows how to retrieve the private key:

```
public PrivateKey decryptKey(byte[] pkcs8Data, char[] password) throws Exception {
    PBEKeySpec pbeSpec = new PBEKeySpec(password);
    EncryptedPrivateKeyInfo pkinfo = new EncryptedPrivateKeyInfo(pkcs8Data);
    SecretKeyFactory skf = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance(pkinfo.getAlgName());
    Key secret = skf.generateSecret(pbeSpec);
    PKCS8EncodedKeySpec keySpec = pkinfo.getKeySpec(secret);
    KeyFactory kf = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
    return kf.generatePrivate(keySpec);
}
```

If you have a PEM format, remove the header (first line), the footer(last line) et convert the remaining content from base64 to regular byte array.

Comment: I an getting below error while decrypting Private key pem string java.io.IOException: ObjectIdentifier() -- data isn't an object ID (tag = 48)